# Implement sign in via twitter in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to provide functionality to get user sign in via twitter in my app.
I have spend 2 days in just reading the blogs , dev.twitter.com .. but i reached nowhere.
Can anyone help me .. or just tell me any open source app. thats provides this functionality..
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you develop for IOS 5 and later versions just add Twitter.framework to your target.
User uses settings screen to login and logout to twitter

`#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>` in your class/viewcontroller.

then call following method anywhere in your code

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
      //yes user is logged in
     }
else{
      //show tweeet login prompt to user to login
        TWTweetComposeViewController *viewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

        //hide the tweet screen
        viewController.view.hidden = YES;

        //fire tweetComposeView to show "No Twitter Accounts" alert view on iOS5.1
        viewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            }
        };
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];

        //hide the keyboard
        [viewController.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Also look at this tutorials:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21558/beginning-twitter-tutorial-updated-for-ios-6

http://mobileorchard.com/ios-tutorial-twitter-integration-in-ios5/

Comment: what if the user has not created his system twitter account

Comment: this check if user is currently logged in to twitter or not, if not it shows twitter login page that simple.

Answer (score 0):

The Social Framework (iOS6) has built-in twitter functionality that will save you some time. In iOS5 there is a (very) similar Twitter Framework.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use OAuth.  Read "Getting started with OAuth 2.0" by Ryan Boyd

Comment: Also on youtube search for apigee videos on OAuth